# React: How to remove button focus outline from react-bootstrap component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using this CSS

```
.reasonButton:focus{
   color: #fff;
    background-color: #676666;
    border-color: #adadad;
    outline: none;
}
```

Can anybody help me with this problem? 
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
.btn:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    outline-offset: none !important;
}
```

In my case, It was solved by using the above code

Answer (score 5):

```
button:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```